# Why am I getting a segmentation fault in my map-reduce file reading code?

Tags: c, unix, segmentation-fault

I am trying to simulate map-reduce. I have a problem with thread management and passing by reference. When sending a single character it works, but sending a whole struct gives me a segmentation fault.

Each sentence in `text.txt` is separated by a newline (`\n`).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct sentencetype
{
    char *sentence;
    int length;
}sentencetype;

void *map(void *ptr){
  sentencetype allQueuesSingle = *((sentencetype*) ptr);

  printf("%c", allQueuesSingle.sentence[0]);
  //why doesnt this print the first letter in each line

  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void) {
  char letter;
  int mapthreadsSize = 0, sentenceSTRSize = 0;
  pthread_t *mapthreads = malloc(sizeof(pthread_t));

  sentencetype *sentenceSTR;

  int fd = open("text.txt", O_CREAT | O_RDONLY, 0777);

  sentenceSTRSize = 1;
  sentenceSTR = malloc(sentenceSTRSize * sizeof(sentencetype));
  sentenceSTR[0].sentence = malloc(sizeof(char));
  sentenceSTR[0].length = 0;

  while (read(fd, &letter, 1)){
    sentenceSTR[sentenceSTRSize-1].length++;
    sentenceSTR[sentenceSTRSize-1].sentence = realloc(
        sentenceSTR[sentenceSTRSize-1].sentence,
        sentenceSTR[sentenceSTRSize-1].length * sizeof(char));
    sentenceSTR[sentenceSTRSize-1].sentence[sentenceSTR[sentenceSTRSize-1].length-1] = letter;

    if(sentenceSTR[sentenceSTRSize-1].sentence[sentenceSTR[sentenceSTRSize-1].length-1] == '\n'){

      //send sentence
      mapthreadsSize++;
      mapthreads = realloc(mapthreads, mapthreadsSize * sizeof(pthread_t));
      
      pthread_create(&mapthreads[mapthreadsSize-1], NULL, map, &sentenceSTR[sentenceSTRSize-1]);

      sentenceSTRSize++;
      sentenceSTR = realloc(sentenceSTR, sentenceSTRSize * sizeof(sentencetype));
      sentenceSTR[sentenceSTRSize-1].sentence = malloc(sizeof(char));
      sentenceSTR[sentenceSTRSize-1].length = 0;
    }
  }
  
  //send last sentence
  mapthreadsSize++;
  mapthreads = realloc(mapthreads, mapthreadsSize * sizeof(pthread_t));
  pthread_create(&mapthreads[mapthreadsSize-1], NULL, map, &sentenceSTR[sentenceSTRSize-1]);

  for (int i = 0; i < mapthreadsSize; i++) {
    pthread_join(mapthreads[i], NULL);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Take the [tour] and read [ask].  Where exactly does the segfault occur? Have you tried debugging your code? Got any theories regarding why it might be failing?

Comment: `sentenceSTR[sentenceSTRSize-1].sentence = malloc(sizeof(char));` - just `= NULL`. No need to reallocate `mapthreads = ` each loop, if your going to relalocate it after the loop anyway. `while (read(fd, &letter, 1))` is strange, better do `while (read(..) == 1)`. Note that `char *sentence;` is __not__ a string - it's missing terminating zero character. `pthread_join(mapthreads[i]` - you are joining on uninitialization `mapthreads` - you created only `mapthreads[mapthreadsSize-1]` , only join on that one, not on all `0 ... mapthreadsSize-1` threads.

Comment: `printf("%c", allQueuesSingle.sentence[0]);` prints one character because you told it to with `%c`, if you want it to print a string use `%s`.

Answer (score 0):

`realloc()` is allowed to reseat the array. So the pointer that your threads are holding are potentially getting invalidated when you realloc `sentenceSTR`.

A fairly straightforward way to fix this would be to not create the pthreads until you are done processing the entire file.